# Is it okay to upvote multiple answers in a question?

Tags: support, voting, upvotes

Is it okay to upvote multiple answers on the same question?

Real example (present on the site):
Someone asked a programming question and a number of different answers are correct (they used different terminology/method/way).

Can we upvote our own answers too if they're correct? (it sounds unethical though)

Comment: Why would it not be okay?

Comment: I just upvoted some answers of same questions (all of them are correct). I was confused after upvoting them and thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Please note that if there are multiple, correct (normally almost identical) answers to a question, especially if they're posted within a few minutes then the chances are the question is a duplicate. You'd be serving the community better in the longer run by finding the duplicate than by up voting the answers of those who didn't...

Comment: What to do with identical same answers? I saw few answers copied by new members to gain reputation (or whatever they were looking for)

Comment: I don't know why you made that edit to the title but it did not reflect the main content and it would only attract downvotes because of poor research (you can't vote on your own answers).

Comment: It's also ok, as with this question, to downvote questions on meta, but not comment as to why so people have a contrary opinion to debate with... :rollseyes:

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I didn't make the edit, someone else did :)

Comment: I just up voted both answers on this question!

Comment: If there are multiple answers that are (almost) identical, I would only upvote the earliest one. Providing the same answer that's already there is not very helpful. But that's just me, you're obviously free to upvote them all.

Comment: @Reto Okay ... but it all depends on what you call "identical answer". Sometime it is understood as "same code". As of myself, if one answerer took the time to add a decent explanation to its answer, I would favor her, even if other "pseudo-identical" answers (i.e.: same code) were posted before.

Comment: I have seen all the comments and answers here and I realise that you can vote all the answers if you think that all are correct so why shouldn't upvote all answers and there some body given down vote for my question..Why people do that? I dont think my question is copied from another questions.

Answer (score 190):

[image: UPVOTE ALL THE GOOD ANSWERS]

Comment: Like this one :)

Comment: @Alam Feel free to upvote it. And all the others ;)

Comment: I most definitely did not expect to see that when I scrolled down. Well done sir, and thanks for LOLZ.

Answer (score 69):

It's definitely okay to upvote multiple answers, as long as you think they're correct. It's even okay to upvote multiple answers posted by the same person, on the same question, if they're both different and correct.

More generally, your votes are yours to do with as you will. Vote on the post (question and answer) and not the person; vote out of belief and knowledge, not pity and you'd be hard pressed to go wrong.

**You can't upvote your own answers though... Sorry!**

Comment: It's unethical I know that.

Comment: No, you _can't_ @Alam, try it - you won't be allowed to.

Comment: I tried. The system is not allowing me to upvote my own answer. Great!

Comment: Help!! I have got an error! I can't upvote my own post! I want to cheat reputation (and use that rep to ban everybody), but I can't! Someone help!! :(

Comment: LOL! I know it's unethical. I just asked. No harm done, no?

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could upvote my own. It makes me ever so sad to write an answer in a niche topic, and get no rep because no one ever reads it.

Comment: You also can't downvote your own answer.

Comment: @MobyDisk No one wants to downvote their answer/question.

Comment: @Alam if it had very few votes, was accepted, and they wanted it to be eligible to be deleted, they might. :)

Comment: @Alam: I can remember at least one time I wanted to downvote my own answer. I made two different guesses at what the OP wanted in separate answers, got +3 votes on the first and +1 on the second, and the first guess turned out to be wrong. Of course I deleted the answer, but it still felt wrong to me that it had more votes than the correct one. If the OP had actually accepted the wrong one even after clarifying the question, so I couldn't delete it, it might have been worse than "feels wrong".

Comment: @KevinB If the answer is correct, accepted and has votes why on earth someone wants to delete it?

Comment: who says the answer is correct? it's certainly possible for the op to accept a wrong answer. :)

Comment: @abarnert You have some strong explanation there. Great! :)

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, I missed that part.

Comment: "as long as you think they're correct." I'd rather say as long as you **know** they're correct!

Comment: I considered changing it to that @Theo, but decided that they're the same thing on the internet...

Comment: @Ben I don't know, ["I *think* someone is wrong on the internet"](http://xkcd.com/386/) just doesn't have the same ring to it...

Answer (score 10):

It is definitely ok to upvote, and sometimes important to upvote multiple answers because, usually people upvote the one they like, even when there are multiple GOOD answers.

So, I do try to upvote all answers that are good. Conversely, you should also not be afraid to DOWNVOTE multiple answers if one or all of them are terrible! I am in the habit of doing this on all the Q&A sites I visit.

I know how frustrating it can be to post an answer and never get a single vote for my hard work (esp when spending free time, doing research, etc.) so what about this answer? Is it worth it..maybe you should downvote me after all :)